# Merge on the remote master branch

Tags: git, bash, ubuntu

I am currently on a new branch on my device. I would like to merge the modifications I made to the remote branch master.

I think I have to follow this procedure, but I'm not certain :

```
git checkout origin master
git pull origin master
git merge "new_branch"
git push origin master
```

Does this procedure is good?
Is there a more efficient way to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suggested steps are fine (with a few modifications):

```
git checkout master      # removed origin
git pull origin master
git merge new_branch     # removed quotes
git push origin master
```

This approach is to update your local `master` branch with changes, then directly update the remote `master`.  However, if you are using a repo provider like GitHub or Bitbucket, you may not be able to directly update the remote `master` branch.  In this case, you would create a pull request from your branch to `master`, and you would actually do the merge in the *opposite* direction, namely you merge `master` into `new_branch`:

```
git fetch origin         # update origin/master
git checkout new_branch
git merge origin/master
git push origin new_branch
```

From here, you would create a pull request in GitHub or whatever service you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply fetch, and then merge

```
git checkout newbranch
git fetch
git merge origin/master
```

Here, `fetch` is enough to update your remote tracking branches (the ones in your `.git/refs/remotes/origin`): you can merge directly from one of those, like `origin/master`.
I like [`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) because it won't change any file in your working tree, so it is a safe first step.
[`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) would fetch plus merge into your current branch.

As an additional step, you can update your local master branch if you want.
I would recommend

```
git config --global pull.rebase true
git config --global rebase.autoStash true
```

That way, this is enough, even if you have made some local commits on master, and have some pending modifications:

```
git checkout master
git pull
```

Comment: could you tell me the difference between fetch and pull?

Comment: `git pull = git fetch + git merge` (for the most part)